# Override a TestBed Provider for specific test

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I have a component, which has two dependencies: one is `LOCALE_ID` defined globally in angular, another is language, defined in the Component as `{ provide: LANGUAGE_TOKEN, useValue: navigator.language }`

For testing, I am both overriding them in TestBed for all tests, so tests don't get anything injected from the Chrome browser doing the karma tests, and tests don't have different result based on testing environment:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent, RouterStubComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule, RouterTestingModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' },
  ]
}).compileComponents();

TestBed.overrideProvider(LOCATION_TOKEN, {useValue: locationStub});
TestBed.overrideProvider(LANGUAGE_TOKEN, {useValue: 'en-US' });
```

Now I have some logic in the component that depends on locale and browser language, so I need to mock them. Mocking `LANGUAGE_TOKEN` was super easy, barely an inconvenience:

```js
 it('should redirect to spanish when in spanish browser', () => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(LANGUAGE_TOKEN, {useValue: 'es'});
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(hrefSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(hrefSpy.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(environment.spanUrl);
  });
```

However override `LOCALE_ID` with same code doesn't work.

```js
  it('should ...', () => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(LOCALE_ID, {useValue: 'es-ES'});
    console.log(TestBed.get(LOCALE_ID)); // en-US!!!!
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MamanComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(hrefSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1); //FAIL
    expect(hrefSpy.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(environment.engUrl);//FAIL
  });
```

I was unable to find a working answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811091/how-override-provider-in-angular-5-for-only-one-test) either.

Comment: Try removing LOCALE_ID from configureTestingModule, because as soon as you call compileComponents, the providers are frozen and won't  be overridden. If that doesn't work, try removing compile components and creating component instance in every test. It's simpler with services, but with compoent instance, you will have to call compileComponents with every test before creating the component instance(never tried it).

Comment: I tried it, it should work

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is because as soon as you call `compileComponents`, the providers are frozen and won't be overridden.

Either remove `LOCALE_ID` from the `providers` so that it's value is not frozen. (But make sure to provide it using `overrideProviders` before **creating the component instance**):

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent, RouterStubComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule, RouterTestingModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    --> remove 
  ]
}).compileComponents();

TestBed.overrideProvider(LOCALE_ID, {useValue: 'es-ES'});
//Add it before creating component, to have a default value in each test, add it in a beforeEach block.
```

Or you can call `compileComponents` before creating component instance in each test:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [
    MyComponent, RouterStubComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    MatToolbarModule, RouterTestingModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'en-US' },
  ]
});
--> remove compileComponents
```

Then in every test :

```
it('should ...', () => {
    TestBed.overrideProvider(LOCALE_ID, {useValue: 'es-ES'});
    // Add here
    TestBed.compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MamanComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(hrefSpy.calls.count()).toBe(1); //FAIL
    expect(hrefSpy.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toEqual(environment.engUrl);//FAIL
  });
```

Comment: so why does it work in the first case, overriding `LANGUAGE_TOKEN`?

Comment: You don't have LANGUAGE_TOKEN in providers array, you can also do something similar with LOCALE_ID. 
Remove it from providers array and just add it via overrideProviders before creating the component instance. Let me update the answer for more clearity.

Comment: In a service test, this still doesn't work. I'm getting always the value declared while configureTestingModule and not the one that i provided as an override. Any news on that?