# Unable to override provider in angular 9

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test, angular-jest

When trying to override provider in test case using, `Testbed.overrideProvider` it doesn't actualy override anything.

It used to work fine angular 9 with jasmine, not sure what has changed in angular 9 which has broke it.

Any help will be appriciated.
in my app html component I am removing `.bg-image` when layout$ contains 'mobile'.

Here is what I have:

**app.component.spec.ts**

```js
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule,
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: BreakpointService,
          useValue: {
            layout$: of('web')
          }
        }
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
```

and in my one of test cases **it()**, I am doing

```js
    TestBed.overrideProvider(BreakpointService, {
      useValue: { layout$: of('mobile') }
    });
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const imageElem = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.bg-image'));
    expect(imageElem).toBeFalsy();
```

I used to overrideProvider like this with angular 6 and hadn't been using angular for a while now. Today I started working on a new project with angular 9 and even tho it has these same methods mocking with `overrideProvider` doesn't work anymore.
I know there is actually lot changed since angular 6, like default test framework has changed from jasmine to jest and new ivy render and many more. But my question remains, I am not sure if this is a bug, or I am just being dumb. I just wanted to ask someone with more experience here before I go ahead and open an issue in repo.

Comment: Please provide code and possible errors that pop up.

Comment: If it used to work, what did you change now that it doesn't? We will need a bit more info to help out

Comment: Added more description now

Comment: I experience the same issue after upgrade from angular 7 to 9 it stopped working. There is no specific error it's just the fact that Provider doesn't have the overridden value. Is this a bug in NG9?

Comment: seems like that, and no one has come across it but me? No one seems to talking about it

Comment: As discussed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811091/how-override-provider-in-angular-5-for-only-one-test, TestBed is frozen after calling `compileComponents()` and overrideProvider has no effect.